# How do you mirror a specific branch to a branch in another repository?

Tags: git, github

I want to mirror only the master branch in "old repository" to a branch "X" in the 
"new repository". How do i do this? [To be clear I do not want to mirror the whole repo or the other branches]

Once i mirror this, at some point I will want to take "X" and merge all the new changes into the "master" of the "new repository". I know i can do a pull request but how would i do this through the terminal?

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding the old repository as a remote with `git remote add <name> <url>` and then fetch one or more branches with `git fetch <name> <branch> ...`. Then you can work with it like any other remote branches and merge your branches normally with `git merge <name>/<branch>`.

I would advise against it except in certain circumstances like an enormous branch with lots of big files (which would benefit from using `git-lfs`). It's extra complexity you don't need.

Because of how Git works, most branches will share the majority of the repository. Once you fetch one open branch, fetching other branches comes at a low cost. For example...

```
                                       Q - R - S [branch2]
                                      /
A - B - F ------ G - H - I - J - K - O - P [master]
     \          /                 \
      C - D - E                    L - M - N [branch1]
```

If you `git fetch old branch1` you'll get commits N, M, L, K, J, I, and everything else all the way back to A. If you then `git fetch old branch2` it will only fetch Q, R, and S. So unless your repository is oddly structured, fetching branches after the first comes at a very low cost. Might as well <strike>catch</strike> fetch em all and make the whole process simpler.

Comment: If it gives error like `fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories`. Add this option at end of command `--allow-unrelated-histories`

For ex. `git merge <name>/<branch> --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: @SaumyaSuhagiya Also be sure you know what you're doing. "unrelated histories" means the two branches have nothing in common. Merging unrelated histories is only a good idea on specific circumstances.